# Application not running on android

Tags: android

I am getting this error after i installed Android Studio and opened an application.

[image]

Comment: please try to add the error in detail with your gradle code and what you have done so far

Comment: Errors in pictures are totally useless when someone tries to find the solution to the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Build Error on Android Studio 3.1.3: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039946/gradle-build-error-on-android-studio-3-1-3-the-server-failed-to-respond-with-a)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your internet on still all dependecy download and sync..
because its may be network fault.. i face this problem before..

If not then go to file->restore and restart project it solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by an unreliable / faulty internet connection. However, if you have intentionally enabled "Offline work", the following will help:

1. Uncheck  `Offline work` in Android Studio, the option is at `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build tools` > `Gradle`.
2. Resync the project, and restart Android Studio.